# How can I call Javascript code from a button in Orbeon Forms CE?

Tags: javascript, rest, orbeon

I am using the Orbeon Forms Community Edition and I wish to create a button to call a javascript method. This method will call a web service that returns a value and this value will be used to update a field on the form. In particular, I wish to get the exchange rate for a currency on the form through an available web service. I know that web services feature is fully supported in the Professional Edition but I wish to ask you if I could implement the aforementioned scenario in the Community Edition. If so, is there available any sample that presents the implementation of a similar case?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a process which calls the [`navigate()` action](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner#navigate), which also supports the `javascript:` scheme.

Then you can use the [client-side JavaScript API](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/client-side-javascript-api) to set a control value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I just wish to ask you if there is any available example showing a similar process since I am not very experienced with Orbeon Forms. I've read the links mentioned above but I do not feel very confident to implement this kind of functionality!

Comment: Hi, I've managed to define a button & a process in the properties-local.xml file but for some reason, I cannot update the value of the input field. Please check my sample below: <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.NoonReport.Noon_Report">
  summary clear pdf save-final send-to-myservice review
 </property>

 <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send-to-myservice.NoonReport.Noon_Report">
  navigate(uri = "javascript:ORBEON.fr.API.findControlsByName('vessel-name')[0].value ='test vessel'")   
 </property>